Why is the \[ThickSpace] character defined as 5/18 em instead of 1/4 em as in Unicode?
I recently discovered that the \[ThickSpace] character in Mathematica is represented as $5/18\, \mathrm{em}$ from the documentation, in which I also find that its Unicode is 2005.
However, when I searched U+2005 and find that character's name is "Four-Per-Em Space", which means that its width is $1/4\, \mathrm{em}$ in Unicode.
As $\frac14=\frac{9}{36}$ and $\frac5{18}=\frac{10}{36}$, there is not much difference between them. What is the reasoning behind Mathematica setting U+2005 to $5/18\, \mathrm{em}$?

As explained in the UnicodeMath:

In mathematical typography, the widths of spaces are usually given in integer multiples of an eighteenth of an em.

This is also implemented in $\TeX$, which in math mode uses a length unit mu, such that $$\text{mu} = 1/18\;\text{em}.$$
Other whitespace characters in Mathematica behave similarly, for example \[VeryThinSpace] (1/18 em) or \[MediumSpace] (4/18 em).
